# How to address a float to write 4 individual bytes to it in C?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-warnings

I have a function that expects a 32 bit float, however in a certain mode it expects the float to actually just be 4x UINT8s packed together.

The code I have written works however I get a compiler warning "illegal pointer" warning and I want to know what is the most "correct" way to do it? Code readability is very important as well, I consider what I've written to be quite easily read despite there probably being ways to write it in less lines.

```
UINT8 time[6];
FLOAT FSTtime = 0;    //32bit float
UINT8 * FSTtimePointer;

//Get the current time as 6 bytes {secs,mins,hours,day,month,year}
returnSize = appP->DB_get_param_value(12, 0, 8, &time);
if (returnSize < 6) return;

(UINT8*)FSTtimePointer = &FSTtime;   //Line 876

//Pack 4 bytes of time data into a "float"
FSTtimePointer [0] = time[3];  //Reverse month & day because americans are backwards
FSTtimePointer [1] = time[4];
FSTtimePointer [2] = time[2];
FSTtimePointer [3] = time[1];

appP->HIST_write_FST_log(SubMin_CFG.OFFSET, (UINT16)historyPointer, FSTtime);
```

The prototype for HIST_write_FST_log is

```
  void   (*HIST_write_FST_log) (UINT8 hist_pt_index, UINT16 log_index, FLOAT value);
```

The compiler warnings I get are:

```
876: C1000 (W) Illegal pointer assignment
876: C1024 (W) First operand of "=" is not lvalue
```

In case anyone is interested the compiler I am using is the Renesas H8 for hitachi processors.

Comment: Without trying it, you probably only need to move the cast to the right side of the equal. `FSTtimePointer = (UINT8*)&FSTtime;` Readability looks fine to me.

Comment: I agree, moving the cast is probably all that needs done to make it work, but I think that using a casted pointer is not going to be very understandable. I've posted an answer using a union, which is a clear way to indicate that you want to access individual bytes of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use revise the code as folllowing

FSTtimePointer = (UINT8*) &FSTtime;

Comment: Well that certainly gets rid of the warning, I obviously had the cast backwards.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this is how you want to store the time? The internals of a floating-point data type are not usually aligned on byte barriers, and dates are usually the seconds or milliseconds from the epoch (usually as a `UINT32` or `UINT64`), not as a floating-point type. You may also need to take into account MSB- or LSB-byte ordering in your processor. (Disclaimer: I do not know how Hitachi processors handle byte ordering or floating-point datatypes.)

If you are certain that this is how you want to do it, you should be able to use a `union` to address the individual bytes in a larger datatype:

```
union converter_type
{
    UNIT8 elements[4];
    FLOAT whole;
} converter;

UINT8 time[6];
FLOAT FSTtime = 0;    //32bit float

//Get the current time as 6 bytes {secs,mins,hours,day,month,year}
returnSize = appP->DB_get_param_value(12, 0, 8, &time);
if (returnSize < 6) return;

//Pack 4 bytes of time data into a "float"
converter.elements[0] = time[3];  //Reverse month & day because Americans are backwards
converter.elements[1] = time[4];  // (Yes, we are.)
converter.elements[2] = time[2];  // (But what about Canadians? They're "American", too! ;) )
converter.elements[3] = time[1];
FSTtime = converter.whole;

appP->HIST_write_FST_log(SubMin_CFG.OFFSET, (UINT16)historyPointer, FSTtime);
```

Comment: The API has the following description "If the archive type of hist_pt_index is specified to be an FST time stamp, the 4-bytes of value should be set to MMHHDDMM (minute, hour, day, month)." So it does expect it, it also does work (my packed date shows correctly) but you've raised some interesting points, perhaps there is no true "correct" way.

Comment: The union is only slightly less confusing with more code. I think using the proper cast is my best option. Thanks for your help!